# Cannot aggregate multiple requests from the same microservice using Ocelot

Tags: c#, request, aggregate, aggregation, ocelot

I'm trying to aggregate two requests from the same microservice using Ocelot, but it seems to not be working (when I'm calling the aggregate request route the response is 404). I'm not even sure whether this is possible or not because all the example that I've seen so far for request/result aggregation using Ocelot use routes from distinct microservices.

This is what the ocelot.json file looks like:

```
{
    "GlobalConfiguration": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Aggregates": [
        {
            "RouteKeys": [
                "request1",
                "request2"
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/aggregate/{id}",
            "Aggregator": "RequestAggregator"
        }
    ],
    "Routes": [
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/request1/{id}",
            "DownstreamScheme": "https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "{Service1}"
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/request1/{id}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
                "Get"
            ],
            "SwaggerKey": "service1",
            "Key": "request1"
        },
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/request2/{id}",
            "DownstreamScheme": "https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "{Service2}"
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/request2/{id}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
                "Get"
            ],
            "SwaggerKey": "service2",
            "Key": "request2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also added an instance of the aggregator to the ocelot builder in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration)
    .AddSingletonDefinedAggregator<RequestAggregator>()
```

Comment: The route is URL like `"https://localhost:5000/api/request1/{id}"`.   You can only have one route to each request.